# Display space characters in pre tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, pre

In visual studio and other code editors it is possible to view the white space characters.  These would appear as small ellipses in the line.

Is it possible to mimic this feature in html.  I have been able to use the `pre` tag to display the text but I am at a loss on how to display the white space characters.

Is it possible via CSS or javascript to show the white space characters?

Comment: I would think that you would have to replace the white space character with a visible character such as a small ellipses.  CSS has no character translation feature, but PHP and other languages do.

Comment: I guess the solution would be to replace spaces with dots (i.e.) with javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap each space in your `pre` elements in a `span` with background, so the spaces become visible, but you could copy the text as usually. Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qrxLj/).

Example script (assuming there are no nested tags in the `pre`):

```
var pres = document.querySelectorAll('pre');

for (var i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) {
    pres[i].innerHTML = pres[i].innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '<span> </span>')
}
```

CSS:

```
pre > span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #cc0, rgba(192,192,0,0) 2px);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom font for `pre` elements, in which the whitespace characters are replaced with something visible.

Comment: I went with this approach, as I could use the `span` tags to change the font for spaces.  Instead of `radial-gradient`, I used `&middot;` as this is what I wanted.  Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.  I also, managed to use `&para;` for end of line indicators.

Answer (score 3):

you could replace whitespace chars with the ellipsis symbol, like

```
jsstring.replace(/[\s]/g, "\u2026");
```

where `jsstring` denotes a javascript variable with the text to alter. note that you can get and set the textual representation of an html tag including its contentby means of the jquery `html()` function.

in case you wish to keep line breaks, use

```
jsstring.replace(/[ \t]/g, "\u2026");
```

(example available on [jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/ARu7b/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/ARu7b/3/)).

in fact, `[\s]` is just a shorthand for `[ \t\r\n]`. you may define your own character class containing exactly what you consider to be a whitespace character.

Comment: But surely if you're using `pre` it makes sense to keep `\n`s in place. Could you edit to just have spaces?

Comment: Also, I prefer `\u00B7` - the middle dot Character, as they use a similar thing on Sublime

Comment: @IanClark: sure, choose whatever replacement string suits your needs best. a sequence of center dots is easier to count than ellipses, which might be of advantages in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do that by CSS but in Javascript you can do something like this. Note that I used jQuery; if you are not loading jQuery in your project let me know to change my code to plain JavaScript.

for example you have something like:

```
<pre>
    ul.nav-menu { list-style: none; }
    ul.nav-menu li:last-child { border: none; }
    ul.nav-menu li a { color: #b3b3b3; display: block;  }
</pre>
```

You can do:

```
<script>
    var text = $("pre").html();
    $("pre").empty()
    words = text.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        $("pre").append(words[i] + '%');
    }
</script>
```

And it will replace spaces with any characters like '%' or whatever.
Result will be:

```
ul.nav-menu%{%list-style:%none;%}
ul.nav-menu%li:last-child%{%border:%none;%}
ul.nav-menu%li%a%{%color:%#b3b3b3;%display:%block;%%}
```